# linux slackware: boring error with firefox

Tags: firefox

This strange error is really simple.
But i don't know how to solve
I download a html page,for example

```
site.com.html
```

When i click on download icon(blue arrow on top right side)
and i open..it open `audacious`
which is a  mp3 player!
I don't want to play html file or folders but open
it with my file manager which is thunar xfce.
How to do?
Of course i've tried to associate html with firefox
and folder with thunar from firefox options

Comment: You could go to `about:support` and try `Refresh Firefox…` there (if you're OK with the effects of this button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to play html file or folders but open it with my file manager which is thunar xfce.

If I understood you correctly your directories *and* your html files are opened with `audacious` for some reason? (I apologize if I'm mistaken)

In XFCE you change that like this:

- Go to `Applications Menu >> Settings >> MIME Type Editor`
- Find `text/html` and change it to your web browser (e.g. firefox)
- Find `inode/directory` and change it to your file browser (e.g. thunar)

You can also do this manually by editing `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and adding the follwoing:

```
[Default Applications]
inode/directory=thunar.desktop
text/html=firefox.desktop
```

> Of course i've tried to associate html with firefox and folder with thunar from firefox options

Normally default applications and MIMEs are handled by DE.
Firefox has nothing to do with this changing anything in Firefox's options would have no effect on whether `text/html` is opened by `audacious` or not.

Comment: The second solution editing the file is not working,but using the gui settings yes,thanks